# Displaying 3D Buildings in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I am using `OpenLayers` 3 to render OSM map data into `WebBrowser` control in my C#-WPF application. The reason for using OpenLayers v3 is that it supports map rotation.

The version of Internet Explorer is 10. This is a limitation for using OL3-Cesium for displaying 3D buildings on my map.

I have come across another library `OSMBuildings` for 3D buildings. This API works with OpenLayers 2 which unfortunately does not support map rotation.

I would like some help with using [**OSMBuildings**](http://osmbuildings.org) with **OpenLayers 3** or a workaround for **OL3-Cesium API** to work in **Internet Explorer 10 or lower**.

Answer (score 2):

Cesium requires WebGL, which is not supported in Internet Explorer versions before 11. If you are required to use Internet Explorer 10 or lower, Cesium (or anything WebGL-based) is simply not an option.

While I'm not as familiar with OSMBuildings, I believe that getting it to work with OpenLayers 3 is a significant undertaking and would require large changes to the code base (though I could be wrong).  You might want to chime in on [this issue](https://github.com/kekscom/osmbuildings/issues/40) in their repository and ask for an official statement from the team.

Unless I'm wrong about OSMBuildings, there is no good answer here.  Your best bet is to replace IE10 with embedded Chrome or Webkit (or require IE11), but that's probably a non-starter for you.